# Get Latest Version of a document SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with the following SQL

```
SELECT c1.* FROM rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais c1 
left join rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais c2 
on c1.document_id = c2.document_id and c1.versao < c2.versao
where c1.id_projeto = 15 
and c1.id_req_fun = 5
and c2.document_id is null 
order by ordem ASC;
```

I've tried by a subselect also

```
SELECT *
FROM rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais A
WHERE versao = (
    SELECT MAX(versao)
    FROM rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais B
    WHERE B.document_id = A.document_id
)
and id_req_fun = 5
order by ordem asc;
```

but both returns me

[image: return]

it doesn't get the document_id 1, it should return me 1,2,3 getting the lastest version of them

The table data is below

[image]

The SQL ideia is to get the lastest version of a document_id group(each document_id can has many versions) from a id_project and id_req_fun

I can't find any problem.

Comment: Could you provide more info?  E.g. the original tables c1 and c2?  Some [documention](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) that might be useful.

Comment: @Kyle I altered, the original database data is there and I added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT c1.document_id, MAX(c1.version)
    FROM rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais as c1
   WHERE c1.id_projecto = 15
     AND c1.id_req_fun = 5
GROUP BY c1.document_id
```

I am not sure if i understood properly, but given a project and a req_fun this will give you the latest version for each document in the set.

Now if you want the document (a single one) with the biggest version number try:

```
  SELECT c1.document_id, c1.version
    FROM rmanager.requisitos_nao_funcionais as c1
   WHERE c1.id_projecto = 15
     AND c1.id_req_fun = 5
ORDER BY c1.version DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It shows just what is the max version but I need to get the lastest version of all unique document_id, It's grouped by document id, I can have 5 versions of each document_id. Then I need get the lastest version of all unique document_id.

Comment: The first query only returns me the first version of each unique document_id :(

Comment: Can you please put an example of the result you want, with different data sets?